# Getting BLOB in whole column but text was expected in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I am new to databases. I am running following query in python which is successfully creating and inserting values (using data_entry method) into sqlite  database from csv files. But in year column there are no values but 'BLOB' is showing up. I have tried the data type with INTEGER and TEXT both but still 'BLOB' is showing up. What I am doing wrong here ? Thanks.

```
cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GII(year TEXT, series_index TEXT, series TEXT, rank INTEGER, country TEXT, score REAL, value TEXT )')

def data_entry(i):
    year_i = year[i]
    index_i = index[i]
    series_i = series[i]
    rank_i = rank[i]
    country_i = country[i]
    score_i = score[i]
    value_i = value[i]
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO GII  (year, series_index, series, rank, country, score, value) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                   (year_i,index_i,series_i,rank_i, country_i, score_i, value_i))
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: What is the type of `year_i`?

Comment: Actually it is like 2001, 2002, ... 2016. But i have found the problem. Just converted year_i into `str(year_i)` and it worked